How to connect api management with ingress controller with private ip?
reviewing the documentation on how to configure API management, it indicates that an ingress controller can be created for communication between API management and AKS, is it necessarily mandatory for the ingress controller to have a public IP? What happens if I need the ingress controller to have a private IP, can a standard or standardv2 type API management be configured to connect to the ingress controller with a private IP or is it required to change to developer or premium type to integrate it within the AKS vnet and be able to communicate.

Try using the Standard v2 or Premium tier of APIM, which supports virtual network (VNet) integration necessary for private communication @cekodis681 refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-kubernetes


Connecting api management with ingress controller with private ip

It's not always mandatory to have public IP for Ingress Controller.
Instead, you can integrate your APIM instance into same kind of vnet as the cluster and configure it for private communication.
As per the  Microsoftdoc using the Standard v2 or Premium tier of APIM, which supports virtual network (VNet) integration necessary for private communication is possible.
Refer:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/concepts-network-ingress?source=recommendations
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/api-management/api-management-kubernetes.md
How to connect api management with ingress controller with private ip? - Microsoft Q&A

No, the ingress controller doesn’t need a public IP. You can use Standard or Standardv2 API Management with a private IP.
There’s no need to switch to Developer or Premium tiers for VNet integration; just ensure both are in the same VNet or peered VNets for communication.
